# Make incollection of `biblatex-sbl` behave more like CMS and Turabian

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sbl

Even though the SBLHS2 blog references CMS [here](https://sblhs2.com/2017/03/23/citing-chapter-single-authored-work/), they do the bibliography entry for citing an individual part of an edited work differently than CMS 17. SBLHS2 puts "Pages .... in" before the title of the edited work, whereas CMS17 14.107 (as well as Turabian 9 17.1.8.2) both put the pages toward the end. Here is a MWE for `biblatex-sbl`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@collection{EFIMI1986,
  title = {Early Judaism and Its Modern Interpreters},
  editor = {Kraft, Robert A. and Nickelsburg, George W. E.},
  location = {Philadelphia and Atlanta},
  publisher = {Fortress and Scholars Press},
  date = {1986}
}

@incollection{attridge:EFIMI1986,
  crossref = {EFIMI1986},
  author = {Attridge, Harold W.},
  title = {Jewish Historiography},
  pages = {311-343},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
An entry in an edited work.\autocite{attridge:EFIMI1986}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Here is what CMS17 14.107 and Turabian 9 17.1.8.2 have, which is what I am looking for:

[image: CMS17]

[image: Turabian9]

This of course is also true for other things "like" an edited work, such as SBLHS2 §6.2.13, §6.2.22, §6.2.23, §6.3.3, etc. However, these can all be done in an `incollection` I think.

I loked at trying to update the `chapter+pagesin` bibmacro in `biblatex-sbl.def` (based upon the `incollection` bibliography driver in `sbl.bbx`). It looks like the pages would need to be added to the `shortseries+number` macro? It should go before the publication data, but I am not sure if it should go before `note`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be a little hard to predict side effects, but at least for your example it should be possible to patch the `incollection` driver to remove the `chapter+pagesin` macro (you probably won't ever use the `chapter` field). Then patch again to add the `pages` field after the `note` field.

I'd patch the driver rather than the `chapter+pagesin` and `shortseries+number` macros to minimise the chance of unintended side effects.

(I notice that in your examples you have a comma separating the `booktitle` and the `bookeditor` rather than a period. SBL seems to prefer a period. I haven't made this change, but you could by further adjusting the `incollection` driver—it might be easier just to redefine it rather than patch.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@collection{EFIMI1986,
  title = {Early Judaism and Its Modern Interpreters},
  editor = {Kraft, Robert A. and Nickelsburg, George W. E.},
  location = {Philadelphia and Atlanta},
  publisher = {Fortress and Scholars Press},
  date = {1986}
}
@incollection{attridge:EFIMI1986,
  crossref = {EFIMI1986},
  author = {Attridge, Harold W.},
  title = {Jewish Historiography},
  pages = {311-343},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{chapter+pagesin}}
  {\usebibmacro{in}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{note}}
  {\printfield{note}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield{pages}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
An entry in an edited work.\autocite{attridge:EFIMI1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I noticed that CMS and Turabian used the comma in the bibliography. I am fine with the period.

Comment: I tried to update the incollection entry, but I could not get it to look like Turabian with the comma before the editor. There are \newunit commands all in the bibmacros so it always adds a period. It looks like I would have to redefine all the bibmacros as well, is that correct? Should I ask a new question and refer to this one, or can you update your answer above? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul, yes you'd need to patch every bibmacro. Biblatex-sbl is not really designed to be flexible. It's meant to follow SBL standards. Perhaps you'd be better off using one of the Chicago styles? Although these are even harder to customisable than biblatex-sbl. If it's better to keep using biblatex-sbl, it's best to ask a new question

Comment: David, yes, I was using biblatex-chicago for a while. But as you say, it was nearly impossible to patch to get lexicons, dictionaries, ANF, etc, to work. I have lots of tex.se questions from a few years ago attempting. biblatex-sbl gets me 95% of the way there, so I would like to keep using it. I will ask a new question. Thanks!